# How to define schema & database for a Neptune database using Python / Gremlin?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I've recently started out building a graph database using AWS Neptune. Is there a way to define schema and create database using [gremlin_python](https://pypi.org/project/gremlinpython/)?

Any tutorial recommendation would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Neptune has implicit schema which is sometimes called "schemaless". This means that it does not require the schema to be defined ahead of time.  To get started all you need to do is begin adding your data using Gremlin.  The "schema" of the data is created by the types of data that are written.  e.g. `g.addV('person').property('age', 41)`  will create a vertex with label called `person` and a property called `age`.